# Php uploaded file name

Tags: php

I am a little confused about

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

entry. In some examples the `basename` function is applied to that value while in some there is not.
Is it necessary to use `basename`? Should not

```
$FILES[name]
```

always contain just a uploaded file name?

Comment: take a look at **move_uploaded_file()** function, in ['tmp_name'] the binary upload file is stored ... in practice (in my projects) i don't use the originalfile name as filename to store on server ... even i handle it in db

Answer (score 0):

there is no necessary to use basename:

use following code:

```
$rand_name=rand(000000,999999);   //apend random no. to image name
$filen = "$rand_name".$_FILES["userfile"]['name']; 
$image_path = 'upload/'.$filen;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]['tmp_name'],$image_path))
{
    $pic_name=$filen;
}
```

Comment: 1.) So why do some examples use basename?

Comment: Basename also return file name so some are using that also